# How to prove the following xor equation?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In a test paper, a question is given as :

```
Let, x1^x2^x3^x4 =0 where x1, x2, x3, x4 are Boolean variables,and ^ is the XOR operator.

Which one of the following must always be TRUE?
(A) x1x2x3x4 = 0
(B) x1x3+x2 = 0
(C)  x1'^x3' = x2'^x4'
(D) x1+x2+x3+x4 = 0

+ is OR and concatenation is AND operator.
```

Correct answer is C, which I guessed because when all booloean variables are 1, then, neither A,B, or D will hold,**But what is the correct way to get to option C?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I use the symbol $\oplus$ here because $\wedge$ is mathematically used for conjunction ("and") instead of exclusive-or)

First we rearrange the terms,
\begin{align}
 x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_4 &= 0 \\
 x_1 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_4 &= 0 \\
 x_1 \oplus x_3 &= x_2 \oplus x_4
\end{align}
Then use $a \oplus b = a' \oplus b'$ to get (C).
$$ x_1' \oplus x_3' = x_2' \oplus x_4' $$

Comment: how to get symbol you mentioned? It is not present on my keyboard.

Comment: You have to use LaTeX code which is rendered using MathJax on this site.

Comment: Whats the procedure for that?

Comment: @SumeetSingh you may check out http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score -1):

Xor means when we get two same variables answer is 0. That is 0^0=0 and 1^1=0. it is possible to get x1^x2^x3^x4=0 if and only if x1^x2==x3^x4